# How can an operator be diagonalizable on its nontrivial root subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, jordan-normal-form

My question is about the following problem from "Introduction to representation theory" by Etingof et al.

> **Problem 2.15.1 d):**
> Prove that $H$ is diagonalizable on the root subspace $\overline{V}(\lambda)$.

Here $H$ is the "Cartan subalgebra" element of $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, such that $[H, E]=2E$, $[H, F]=-2F$, $[E, F]=H$, and $\overline{V}(\lambda)$ is its root subspace corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, the representation is assumed to be finite-dimensional.

My confusion here is about linear algebra, not representation theory itself. My linear algebra course was quite a while ago, and from it I remember that every finite-dimensional operator can be decomposed into a direct sum of "Jordan normal operators" that act each on its own root subspace. Each root subspace contains precisely one eigenvector and an arbitrary number of generalized eigenvectors; the Jordan's normal operators act on generalized eigenvectors (in a certain basis) as follows: $J|\lambda_{k}\rangle = \lambda |\lambda_{k}\rangle + |\lambda_{k-1}\rangle$, where $k$ enumerates generalized eigenvectors of the given root subspace, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $|\lambda_{0}\rangle =|\lambda \rangle$ is the eigenvector of the root subspace.

It has been my understanding ever since I learned this that the action of an operator on a root subspace cannot be diagonalized, if the root subspace is not trivial (i.e., does not consist of a single eigenvector). Have I misunderstood this part, is the real statement of Jordan's decomposition theorem that the actions on root subspaces cannot be diagonalized simultaneously, and that on **individual** root subspaces the action can still be diagonalized? Otherwise the problem's formulation looks odd.

**Edit:** As another option, the problem may imply that no generalized eigenvectors exist in such representation. However, this is quite a strange way to formulate such statement.

Comment: Given any random linear operator $H: V \to V$ on a finite-dimensional vector complex vector space $V$, we know that $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}} V^\lambda$ where $V^\lambda$ is the generalised eigenspace for $\lambda$. The amazing fact about finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representations is that (a) $V^\lambda \neq 0$ implies that $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that the action of $H$ is diagonalisable. One way to start seeing this is to consider $E^n F^n$ restricted to $\operatorname{ker} E$: it is equal (use induction) to $(H-0)(H-1)\cdots(H-(n-1))$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but if you read the post carefully, you will realize that your comment answers a slightly different question